# How to programmatically check for connection?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, scripting

In Linux (Ubuntu), I want to programmatically check if there is Internet connection (or if eth0 is connected).

I'm doing this because I am writing a program that requires network connection on a system that is highly prone to lose connection.

So I was thinking maybe a script that I can run periodically to check.

Can you give me good suggestions?

Comment: well you can use cron to execute a script based on an interval, with regard to checking the connection you could maybe use the results of a ping or ifconfig to determine if the connection is up, lots of suggestions of this sort on this thread http://serverfault.com/questions/15776/how-to-check-the-physical-status-of-an-ethernet-port-in-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick script that will accomplish what you want:

```
EMAIL=youremail@something.com
ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 >> /dev/null

if [ $? -eq  0 ]
    then
    echo "Able to reach internet!" | mail $EMAIL
else
    echo "Unable to reach internet!" | mail $EMAIL
fi
```

Obviosly you can change the mail to something else to do depending on what your goal is
EDIT: to explain, this pings googles dns server to ensure you are connected and sends you an email one way or the other.  The email part on failure will only work of course if you have a local email server on your network.

Comment: beat me to it :) I was also thinking in using ping but with a count of 1, and without sending the email, since it can accumulate lots of emails in the local mail queue. As a side note, beware that using a google server *may* violate their usage terms (not sure about this), so it would be best to use your own server

Comment: I use a count of 5 to avoid catching little blips which may be out of your control.  If the connection is even more critical 1 would do fine.  I also just used the email as an example of a process to run.  Anything would do really.  Maybe an ifup eth0 on failure.  No idea on the Google TOS, just an easy public IP to hit.

Answer (score 1):

`/sbin/ifconfig` would be an excellent "get adapter status" command to script.

`cron` would be an excellent way to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to `ping` or perhaps `wget` some distant server (preferably the one you want to connect to). The network could work well on the local campus, but not well on intercontinental connections (e.g. because some cables has been cut).